# C++ release sequence details

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

[image: C++ concurrency in action]

I learned that the purpose of the **release sequence** is to make a write operation in one thread sync with many read operations in other threads.

But I still can not understand some details after reading two reference items below.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)

1. Writes performed by the same thread that performed A
   (until C++20)
2. Atomic read-modify-write operations made to M by any thread

1.Dose "Writes performed by the same thread" mean something like below?

```
void foo()
{
    count.store(release)
    ....
    count.store(release)
}
```

Why emphasize a write operation **in the same thread**? And why only emphasize **a write(not read)** operation?

2.Do operations in other thread must RMW like atomic::fetch_sub ? Can it be a normal read operation like atomic::load?

Comment: You want to make sure `queue_data`'s changes are made visible to other threads before (or at least at the same time) as the new `count`. That is why ordering within the thread is important.

Answer (score 0):

A release sequence is a maximal contiguous subsequence of the modification order of an atomic object. It is headed by a release operation *A* and followed by an arbitrary number of:

- atomic operations performed by the same thread that performed *A* or
- atomic read-modify-write operations.

For operations following *A* it is not relevant which memory order is used - they can even use `memory_order_relaxed`. If a thread is reading a value that is part of a release sequence using acquire semantics, this read synchronizes with the release operation that is heading the sequence.

Note that there can exist several release sequences on the same object at the same time. Suppose there are two release-CAS operation on some atomic object *A*. Since both use release semantics, they both act as head of their own release sequence. And since a CAS is an atomic read-modify-write operation, the second CAS is also part of the release sequence headed by the first CAS. So an acquire-load on *A* that returns the value stored by the second CAS will actually synchronize-with *both* release-CAS operations.

To answer your questions - load operations are never part of a modification order (since by their very nature they do not modify an object), and are therefore not part of a release sequence.

> 1.Dose "Writes performed by the same thread" mean something like below?
>
> ```
> void foo()
> {
>    count.store(release) // A
>    ....
>    count.store(release) // B
> }
> ```
>
> Why emphasize a write operation in the same thread? And why only emphasize a write(not read) operation?

Yes, it means something like your example, even though the second store (which I annotated with "*B*") can even be relaxed. *A* would be the head of the release sequence, and any load by some thread that observes the value written by *B* would synchronize-with *A*. As already mentioned, load operations are not part of a modification order and are therefore not part of a release sequence.

> Do operations in other thread must RMW like atomic::fetch_sub ? Can it be a normal read operation like atomic::load?

Yes, any read-modify-write operation can be part of a release sequence, regardless of which memory order is used or which thread performed it. Again, load operations are irrelevant for the release sequence.

In your example, the release sequence ensures that every acquire-fetch-sub synchronizes-with the initial release-store, even though the value a fetch-sub observes was potentially written by some previous fetch-sub instead of the release-store that is the head of the release sequence, thus ensuring that you have the necessary happens-before relation between `populate queue_data` and `process queue_data`.